# How do I fix the wrongly generated Scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, code-generation, ruby-on-rails-7, rails-generate

For convenience let's say we run the following:
`bin/rails generate scaffold Candidate::Test`

The generating function then proceeds to generate all the major components on the corresponding module names. Everything should work fine if I do a `rails test` right after generating the scaffold but I get the following error.

```
Candidate::TestsControllerTest#test_should_show_candidate_test:
RuntimeError: Neutered Exception ActionView::Template::Error: Missing partial candidate/tests/_test with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}.
```

And here's what the error suggested:
`Did you mean?  candidate/tests/candidate_test`

There's something wrong with the naming of the generator. What should I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read link https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/generators.html

Rails: 7.0.3

Ruby: 3.1.2

And I run `bin/rails generate scaffold Candidate::Test` => It's okie.
[image]